# Is there a way to reset JIT optimizations data at runtime?

Tags: java, benchmarking, jit

I have a java process that benchmarks some long running function. But because of cumulative JIT optimizations every next call to the function performs better then previous calls.

Just using `-Xint` to disable JIT is not an option, because it becomes 10x slower and impossible to benchmark.

Comment: You cannot do this.  You will need to set up your benchmark some other way -- probably using JMH.

Comment: Just restart the virtual machine?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to know how long it takes, why not benchmark that with the optimizations? If you're looking to improve performance, use a Profiler to see where your code spends its time.

Comment: Can you use the `asm` class to modify the bytecode, call it forcing it to re-JIT, then modify it back to its original?  I'd guess that might work.  Or change some variable that was previously constant, if it had speculatively inlined / constant-propagated based on that, it would have to redo optimization.  But see also [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) for potential pitfalls of microbenchmarking.

Comment: @Robert I want to compare results of running with different parameters. Like for first run alpha =1 and for second run alpha=1.5 and etc.